# Jira Tempo Rest API get all worklogs from issue returns no worklogs but on the website i can see worklogs

Tags: jira-rest-api

in my application i download all issues and corresponding worklogs from Jira.
It was slow but worked nicely till few weeks ago.

All issues are downloaded correctly but when i try to get the worklogs i get this:

```
{"self":"https://api.tempo.io/core/3/worklogs/issue/XX-123?offset=0&limit=50","metadata":{"count":0,"offset":0,"limit":50},"results":[]}
```

Checking worklogs via webbrowser shows them correctly.
Not even worklogs that have already worked can be downloaded via the API.

I tried using different users or give the users more rights and also to regenerate the Tempo API Integration token.

Or to use the same jira user for the api who created the worklogs.

Only change to the application i made was replacing the regex logic to get the access and refreshtoken from the response json to the following because my regex (p.e. Regex("""access_token"": ""*?(\w+?)""*?[,|}]")) suddenly failed to get the correct tokens.

```
Dim ThisToken As TempoAPITokenResponse = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of TempoAPITokenResponse)(response.Content)
AccessToken = ThisToken.access_token
RefreshToken = ThisToken.refresh_token
```

Any ideas?

Edit:
This returns some worklogs but not of the issues i want.

```
worklogs?updatedFrom=2023-01-01&offset=0&limit=100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the mistake.

The jira user who was used for the Tempo API Settings (Apps\Tempo\Settings\API Integration and OAuth 2.0) was removed from certain projects.

So as a consequence the worklogs of this projects where invisible to the API GET because permissions work as designed.